# alternative for enums in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, enums

in Android, the first thing you learn is to not use enums but use the `@StringDef` and `@IntDef`.
But what is the alternative in Flutter for an enum?.

is there a way to create your **stringdef** version in Dart?

Comment: From [what I've read about `@IntDef`](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/7so7ne/you_should_strictly_avoid_using_enums_on_android/), it sounds like a premature optimization that a lot of people don't follow.  As for Dart: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/50

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enums are totally fine to use in Dart. You don't need an equivalent to StringDef.